# Ellipsis in UIBarButtonItem in localizations

Tags: ios8, autolayout, xcode6, uibarbuttonitem

In the Interface Builder I have placed `UIToolbar` with two `UIBarButtonItem`s, each hosting `UIButton` inside. Buttons and their titles layouts nicely in original (development) language:

[image: Buttons with titles "Uložit" "Zrušit"]

The problem is, that when I create localization, titles in buttons didn't reflect character count change (i.e. new title width):

[image: Button with titles "Save" "C...el"]

[UI Kit User Interface Catalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIToolbar.html) informs that Auto Layout constraints cannot be used for individual bar button items.

Any idea how to force button to layout correctly?

I am using Xcode 6.1 with app target IOS 8.1.

Comment: Will you please share project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem on my side - I accidentally inserted `UIButton` in `UIBarButtonItem`, so final hierarchy was:

- `UIToolbar`

  - `UIBarButtonItem`

    - `UIButton`
  - `UIBarButtonItem`

    - `UIButton`

It happened in Interface Builder when I dragged `UIButton` into `UIToolbar` and then didn't realize that UIBarButtonItem is in fact a button. Because localization was attached to `UIButton` title, proper layout in fixed-width `UIBarButtonItem` couldn't be reached.